# Mongodb Aggregation framework using mongdb driver 2.2.16 giving "undefined" in resultset

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I just upgraded my mongodb driver from 1.4 to 2.2.16 after getting "depreciated" warning.

The issue seems to be with how aggregation. If I remove $match, it works. Something with $match is giving me "undefined" in resultset.

Here is my aggregation function.

```js
Doc.aggregate(
            {$match: searchCriteria}, //Removing this gives result
            {$project: { title: 1, description:1, createdOn:1, extension:1, workflows: 1, enableWorkflow: 1, numPages:1, userid:1, metadata:1, docGalleryId:1, tags:1, status:1, galleryThumbUrl : { $slice: ["$pages.galleryThumbUrl", 1 ] } } },
            {$unwind: '$galleryThumbUrl'},
            {$sort: {createdOn: -1}},
            {$skip: skip},
            {$limit: items},
            function (err, result) {
                console.log(result); //This gives Undefined
                Doc.populate(result, {path: 'userid', select: 'firstName, lastName, userEmail'}, function (err, docCol) {
                    console.log(err, docCol);
                    console.log('items', items);
                    callback({
                        docs: docCol,
                        showNext: showNext,
                        page: page,
                        items: items
                    });
                });
            }

        );
```

searchCriteria is an object (not a string). Here is what it looks like

```js
{"$and":[{"status":{"$ne":"deleted"}},{"$or":[{"userid":{"$in":["56bf7f25f59d1ff711000005"]}},{"collaboration":{"$elemMatch":{"userid":"56bf7f25f59d1ff711000005"}}}]}]}
```

As I said earlier, this used to work fine but not anymore with update to 2.2.16. I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Where is the code that creates `searchCriteria` object?

Comment: The code that builds searchCriteria is right above. It starts with var searchCriteria = {};searchCriteria.$and = [];  And builds criteria based on parameter passed eventually, getting to what I posted above.

Comment: Can you please [edit] and include it with the question?

Comment: I removed double quotes in the key field and tried again. and it worked. So looks like it is the format of json that aggregate does not like.

Comment: Is there a way to not include double quotes in the key field of the json object?

Answer (score 0):

As suspected, I had to basically get rid of double quotes in my "searchCriteria" formation. So I did,

```
searchCriteria = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(searchCriteria));
```

and it did the trick. This is redundant and may be a better solution is out there but for now, this resolves the issue for me.